# How to solve the following system of partial differential equations?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, math-software, maple

I have a system of partial differential equations:
\begin{align}
& u(a,b,c) \frac{\partial y}{\partial c} = \frac{4}{3} ab, \\
& u(a,b,c) \frac{\partial y}{\partial b} = \frac{2}{3} ac + 2 b^2, \\
& u(a,b,c) \frac{\partial y}{\partial a} = \frac{4}{3} bc.
\end{align}
I tried to solve it using maple as follows. First I define
\begin{align}
pde := u(a, b, c)*(diff(y(a, b, c), c)) = (4/3)*a*b, \\
u(a, b, c)*(diff(y(a, b, c), b)) = (2/3)*a*c+2*b^2, \\
u(a, b, c)*(diff(y(a, b, c), a)) = (4/3)*b*c
\end{align}
Then I use the command: pdsolve(pde). But there is an error. How to solve this system of equations using maple? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your system all contain $\partial_{c} y$ - presumably these derivatives should cycle through $a, b$ and $c$.

Comment: @Bacon, yes, thank you very much. I will edit the post.

Comment: @ LJR : A basic question ; in the system of three equations, what is known and what is unknown ?

Comment: @JJacquelin, thank you very much. $u(a,b,c)$ and $y(a,b,c)$ are unknowns.

Comment: @LJR : OK. That was what I supposed in my answer. If $u(a,b,c)$ was a given function, then the arbitrary function $F$ should be no longer arbitrary and must be computed according to the relationship with $u$, with some conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an atempt to solve the PDE system, leading to :
$$y(a,b,c)=F\left(a\,c\,b^{\frac{1}{2}}+\frac{3}{5}b^{\frac{5}{2}}  \right)$$
with $F$ arbitrary derivable function until no bounding condition is specified.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. Your solution is excellent. There is a small problem. It seems that $u = \frac{4b^{1/2}}{3F'(t)}$.

Comment: You are right. The typo is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is heuristic, but it gets you a solution.

The first and third equations, derivatives with respect to $a$ and $c$ integrate out the same, so it makes sense to let $u(a,b,c)=u(b)$.

You can get a solution by assuming that $u(b)=b^n$.  Then you have to solve for the right value of $n$ to make the derivatives match an exact differential.

Answer (score 0):

The command "pdsolve([pde]);" can solve this system of partial differential equations.

Comment: This might be better introduced as an edit to your Question.  In any case it is so terse that many Readers may have difficulty understanding it as an Answer to the Question.